# Casting String to DateTime

Tags: c#, casting, datetime-format

I have a string in format

> Jul 13 2011  1:07PM

I want to cast it as

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt

    e.g: 13/7/2011 11:49:00 AM //string=Jul 13 2011  1:07PM
```

I am using following code to cast it to date.

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(myDateString).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

This works fine if my day in my string is less than 13

```
Jul 12 2011  1:07PM //this will cast to desire format fine!

    Jul 13 2011  1:07PM //gives error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I understand that it is taking day as month but I can not found a way to cast it to desire format.

Comment: Why are you converting twice? Better try DateTime.Parse() for your purpose.

Comment: I don't undestand completely what you want to achieve. You want to cast original string (ie. Jul 13 2011 1:07PM) to datetime?

Comment: It's a conversion, *not* a cast...

Comment: To string convert it to a string in specific data format.I am then converting it again to datetime.

Comment: That's what we don't understand. Why you're converting it string > datetime > string > datetime, but I take this is just demo, not your functional code.

Answer (score 4):

See [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) :

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "MMM dd YYYY H:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See also [`Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DateTime.TryParse`

```
DateTime dt ;
if (DateTime.TryParse("Jul 13 2011 1:07PM",out dt))
   MessageBox.Show("Converted to Date object");
```

Post that you use the `ToString()` method to get the desired output

```
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is the same as `DateTime.Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the string `Jul 13 2011 1:07PM` to a date:

```
var date = Convert.ToDateTime("Jul 13 2011 1:07PM");
```

Then, convert it to a string in the format you like:

```
var dateText = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks!
I tested all solution,s they were giving same exception. 
Can you point out problem in my code!

Comment: In that case problem in your code was second Convert.ToDateTime as it expected "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" (default format in english culture) and got "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: But anyway, if you know exact format of input, you should use (if only because of speed) DateTime.ParseExact and me or Scorpi0 pointed out.

Comment: Sorry there is something missing yet.I want DateTime not the string.And when i convert it to datetime it automatically convert back to MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: we still have no idea why you're doing string > datetime > string > datetime instead of just stirng > datetime. could you explain this?

Comment: So how can i just convert string to datetime in specified format.

Comment: @Ales let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1409/discussion-between-zain-and-ales)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're searching for this:

```
Date.ParseExact("Jul 13 2011 1:07PM", "MMM d yyyy h:mmtt", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```